# Cut and Paste Buttons working on 1st use of both but after doing it one after another then nothing happens in react js with hooks and anchor tag btn

Tags: javascript, reactjs, copy-paste, paste, cut

this part of the code is safe used

```
const [text, setText] = useState("Enter text here");
```

this is a code of paste function

```
const inputToPaste = () => {
  navigator.clipboard.readText().then((inputX) => {
    document.getElementById("Textbox").value = inputX;
  });
};
```

this is code of a cut function

```
const inputToCut = () => {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
  const userInput = "";
  setText(userInput);
};
```

the text area :

```
<textarea
  onChange={handleOnChange}
  value={text}
  id="Textbox"
  rows="10"
  className="relative mt-10 border-4 max-h-72 min-h-0 border-green-400 text-white bg-gray-600 w-[55rem] max-w-screen-lg h-64 p-2 border-lime-100 rounded-lg focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline-blue-500"
></textarea>
```

both btn :

```
<a
  onClick={inputToCut}
  href="#_"
  className="relative inline-flex items-center justify-start px-4 py-2 overflow-hidden font-semibold transition-all bg-green-400 rounded-md hover:bg-gray-900  active:scale-95 group"
>
  <span className="w-48 h-48 rounded rotate-[-40deg] bg-gray-900 absolute bottom-0 left-0 -translate-x-full ease-out duration-500 transition-all translate-y-full mb-9 ml-9 group-hover:ml-0 group-hover:mb-32 group-hover:translate-x-0"></span>
    <span className="relative w-full text-left text-gray-900 transition-colors duration-300 ease-in-out group-hover:text-green-400">
      Cut
    </span>
  </a>
  <a
    onClick={inputToPaste}
    href="#_"
    className="relative inline-flex items-center justify-start px-4 py-2 overflow-hidden font-semibold transition-all bg-green-400 rounded-md hover:bg-gray-900  active:scale-95 group"
  >
    <span className="w-48 h-48 rounded rotate-[-40deg] bg-gray-900 absolute bottom-0 left-0 -translate-x-full ease-out duration-500 transition-all translate-y-full mb-9 ml-9 group-hover:ml-0 group-hover:mb-32 group-hover:translate-x-0"></span>
      <span className="relative w-full text-left text-gray-900 transition-colors duration-300 ease-in-out group-hover:text-green-400">
        Paste
      </span>
```

I want to ble able to use all buttons in every order

Comment: Not a related to your issue: Using `<a>` as a button is a bad practice and you shouldn't do that

Comment: `document.getElementById("Textbox").value = inputX;` - it's not how you change value in react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying the input element directly doesn't change the value of the `text` variable that you declared with `const [text, setText] = useState("Enter text here")`. You need to call `setText` after reading the clipboard value:

```
const inputToPaste = () => {
  navigator.clipboard.readText().then((inputX) => {
    setText(inputX);
  });
};
```